# Mapbox JS SDK geocoding client undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to use the Mapbox JavaScript SDK to do forward geocoding from a VueJS app. I'm following along with [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/marker-from-geocode/) but can't figure out how to access the Mapbox client.

My imports:

```js
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import mapboxSdk from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk';
```

Then in `mounted`:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = this.mapboxToken;
var mapboxClient = mapboxSdk({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
     container: 'map',
     style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
     center: [0, 0],
     zoom: 10
});
mapboxClient.geocoding.forwardGeocode({
    query: 'Wellington, New Zealand',
    autocomplete: false,
    limit: 1
})
    .send()
    .then(function(response) {
        if (
            response &&
            response.body &&
            response.body.features &&
            response.body.features.length
        ) {
            var feature = response.body.features[0];
            new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(feature.center).addTo(this.map);
          }
    });
```

This produces a `mapboxClient.geocoding is undefined` error. I'm invoking the client the same way the tutorial is. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to replace your `import` statement with this:

```js
import mapboxSdk from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding'
```

That's based on my reading of [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/mapbox-sdk).

> To create a service client, import the service's factory function from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/{service}' and provide it with your access token.

Then you probably get rid of the `.geocoding` part too.

Presumably they package it like this so you don't have to bundle all the code for services you're not using - whereas by accessing it through unpkg you get everything.

Comment: now hitting another issue... any idea why adding the CSS required to make Markers work (https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css) would break the map? it just disappears

Comment: New issue = new question.

Comment: already have one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68107924/mapbox-js-sdk-css-stylesheet-causes-map-to-disappear

just asked on the off chance you might know. thanks