# Mapbox JS SDK CSS stylesheet causes map to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using the Mapbox JavaScript SDK in a VueJS app. I am able to display a map with no issues. Now I'd like to add some markers. I see [on this page](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) that you need to import a CSS stylesheet before markers will work. As suggested in the docs, I've tried both of the following:

1. `import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';` from my Vue Component
2. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css">` from the `<head>` of my `index.html`

With either of these, the map disappears, with no visible warnings or errors in the console. Without these, the map shows up fine, but I get a warning saying:

```
This page appears to be missing CSS declarations for Mapbox GL JS, which may cause the map to display incorrectly. Please ensure your page includes mapbox-gl.css, as described in https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the map div got collapsed to 0 height when the stylesheet was imported. No idea why, but manually setting the height resolved the issue.